# How to create an after_save callback on runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using ruby on rails 2.3.5 .

I have user instance. On run time depending on certain conditions I want to add an after_save callback just for this instance.

The other issue is that this after_save should take a block or a proc as parameter.

What I want is something like this. This is psuedo code.

user = User.first

proc = Proc.new do
 puts 'this is foo'
end

user.after_save proc

Comment: The easiest way is probably to always have an after_save call back that checks if an instance variable is true or false before running. If you can be more specific what you're trying to do I could provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. In the model I would have:

```
attr_accessor :after_save_callback

after_save { |record|
  record.after_save_callback.call unless record.after_save_callback.nil?
}
```

Whereas binding the event can be something like:

```
user = User.first
user.after_save_callback = Proc.new { "actual code" }
```

Comment: thanks but I am looking for a more transparent solution. Model class can't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
@user = User.first

eigen = class << @user; self; end
eigen.after_save do
  puts @user.email
end

@user.save
# prints user.email


@another = User.find(100)
@another.save
# does not print user.email
```