# How can you add an ActiveRecord filter to a specific object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

On Rails 3.2, I want to conditionally add an after_save call on a specific ActiveRecord object. I don't want to use a conditional on the filter because I don't want the object itself to have an responsibility over whether the hook is set or not.

The question is similar to [How to create an after_save callback on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805075/how-to-create-an-after-save-callback-on-runtime) but is relevant to 3.2, not Rails 2.

I have tried calling the filter on the eigenclass, but that doesn't seem to work.

Maybe someone who knows ActiveRecord internals a bit more thoroughly could give some insight?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5777262/643500